# (How) is it possible to stabilize video suffering from this type of shaking?

Tags: after-effects, final-cut-pro-x, final-cut-pro, stabilisation

I have a few videos which are quite shaky: similar to this one:

These are shot with DJI's Action2, which has a fixed aperture of f/2.8.

The main problem here is EIS and DJI's algorithm: in auto mode it always aims to bring EV at 0.

How does it solve this? First it increases ISO to maximal 12800. When this is not enough, it raises the shutter speed to somewhat maximum of 1/30.

However this is a huge drawback, as EIS needs much shorter shutter speeds, typically around 1/100 or even shorter.

Now I can set the exposure manually to have a constant shutter speed of 1/100, and a semi-auto ISO between 100-12800, and this brings back EIS to life. I wish to keep it on auto, as if I forget to change back once I'm shooting in a bright sunny day, 1/100 with f/2.8 and ISO 100 will result overexposed shots.

Taking a bit step further my videos are more similar to this (bit longer) one:

, please check it from 38th second, you can see these artifical ligths are shaking:

[image]

Whereas in just a few milliseconds later:

[image]

I wish to know if there is a way to stabilise these kind of artifacts with FinalCut.

I tried to enable *Stabilization* with various methods, but it seems it just can't realise what I wish to achieve.

I might have to try with AfterEffects, but first I'd need some directing, if this is at all possible. (I would be amazed if not, since Google can even make photos moving these days..)

Answer (score 0):

Every example video they show on their [product page](https://www.dji.com/uk/dji-action-2) is shot in bright daylight, except for a couple which have very low movement, and no artificial light spots in view.

The artefacts you're seeing are from the camera trying to stabilise the footage in software - the smearing is when it fails to do so. From [their site](https://www.dji.com/uk/dji-action-2):

> "HorizonSteady keeps your footage level, no matter how wild the action
> gets. From go-karting to dirt biking, DJI's built-in stabilization
> algorithm detects and corrects camera shake and rotation in
> real-time."

At lower shutter rates with this kind of camera, you're either going to get noisy under-exposed footage with motion blur, or buy a gimbal to smooth out the jumps.  There's not a software solution to fix that amount of blurring that I'm aware of.

Comment: Thank you. DJI actually has a bug in their EIS firmware when using with Auto-Exposure settings: it enables going lower shutter speeds than EIS requirements, so it creates these artifacts. I'm trying to convenience them to prioritize EIS limits over 0.0 EV in low-light conditions, but I'm also seeking for post-solutions, if I they won't offer solution. Gimbal is a no-go for me, I'm not a professional shooter :)

Comment: Even their pocket gimbals might give better results if you sell this one (but I haven't used them for a while)

Comment: Yes, for sure, as gimbals don't need light for stabilization. I like this camera because it's *small*.